# How to sort all columns using linux sort with default parameters?

Tags: algorithm, shell, sorting

I need sort a file by all columns. The input file (test.txt) is:

```
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC148167.6_FG001        mt_CE   test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC148167.6_FG001        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC177833.2_FG001        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC183888.4_FG006        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC185265.3_FG003        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC185443.3_FG004        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC186164.3_FG001        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC186583.3_FG004        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC187903.3_FG004        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC192367.2_FG002        mt_CE   test    -
```

When I sort it directly using `cat test.txt | sort`, I got:

```
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC148167.6_FG001        mt_CE   test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC148167.6_FG001        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC177833.2_FG001        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC183888.4_FG006        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC185265.3_FG003        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC185443.3_FG004        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC186164.3_FG001        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC186583.3_FG004        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC187903.3_FG004        mt      test    -
AC187157.4_FG005        x       AC192367.2_FG002        mt_CE   test    -
```

But we can find the 4th column in the first 2 lines is not sorted.

What's the difference between the `sort` and `sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 -k 5,5 -k 6,6` here? And how to sort by all columns with default parameters?

Comment: Sort by all columns? You need to prioritize columns for sorting. If you want it sorted on 3rd as well as 4th column just pipe the sorted output. Like cat test.txt | sort | sort -k 4

Comment: weird, by default my `sort` produces the ouput you're looking for ; are your delimiters proper spaces and/or tabulations?

Comment: Well I don't know what's up with my `sort`, but I do reproduce [your problem on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/eRu5ah)

Comment: @Aaron The input file is Tab-delimited.

Comment: And the solution would be to define keys in order to correctly compare fields of different lengths, and possibly change the sorting rule to handle non-alphanum characters

Comment: @Aaron Yes and when I used `LC_COLLATE=C; cat test.txt | sort`, I got what I need.

Comment: @FengTian great ! Don't forget to use keys if you want variable-size fields to be correctly compared though, otherwise you're comparing the extra characters to tabulations (which actually probably isn't that problematic since tabulations are quite low on the `C` order)